# Java Appcrash Problem

Tags: java, crash, stack-trace, xuggle, jvm-crash

when I start my Java-Program, I get this error (using Xuggle-library with Webcam):

---

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name:     java.exe
  Application Version:  6.0.260.3
  Application Timestamp:        4dc11607
  Fault Module Name:    libxuggle-ferry-4.dll
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:       4b9493c5
  Exception Code:       c0000005
  Exception Offset:     0000822a
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1031
  Additional Information 1:     0a9e
  Additional Information 2:     0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3:     0a9e
  Additional Information 4:     0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

---

I have already found out, that c0000005 is an access violation.
Is there a way to solve such errors? Or how can I trace this error (Stacktrace or something, or maybe some tools for this)? Does Java create logfiles for such errors. Where can I find them? My Java-Program does not throw any exception. I just get this appcrash and "Java Result: -xxxxxxx" (where xxxxxx is a large number).

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java didn't crash, your dll did, and it took the Java process down with it. You won't see an exception. Typically when the JVM is about to die it creates a file that lists what was going on at the time, and it writes a message to stdout with a path to this file. Here's the beginning of one I got not too long back:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x1002ff3a,
>   pid=4312, tid=2120
>
> JRE version: 6.0_24-b07
>    Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (19.1-b02 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
>   Problematic frame:
>   C  [namechangedtoprotecttheguilty.dll+0x2ff3a]
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>     http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
>   The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
>   See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
>
> ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

and it goes on to list what's in the registers, what the stack frames look like, what's on the heap, environment variable values, etc.

Comment: great answer, but I don't find anything in the stdout that gives me the path of the error log, can you kindly help me solving that ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27729672/java-crashes-when-calling-dll-function-using-jna

Answer (score 2):

The developer of `libxuggle-ferry-4.dll` should fix the library.