# Java crashes when calling dll function using JNA

Tags: dll, java-7, jna, javaw

I'm using JNA to run a dll function:

Here is all the code corresponding to that manner:

**The Native Declarations:**

```
//how the method declared

H264_Login (char *sIP, unsigned short wPort, char *sUserName, char *sPassword, LP_DEVICEINFO lpDeviceInfo, int *error, ，SocketStyle socketTyle=TCPSOCKET); // where LP_DEVICEINFO is a struct

//how the struct declared
typedef struct _H264_DVR_DEVICEINFO
{
    SDK_SYSTEM_TIME tmBuildTime; // the "SDK_SYSTEM_TIME" is another struct
    char sSerialNumber[64];      
    int byChanNum;          
    unsigned int uiDeviceRunTime;  
    SDK_DeviceType deviceTye; // the "SDK_DeviceType" is a enum
}H264_DVR_DEVICEINFO,*LP_DEVICEINFO;

// this is how "SDK_SYSTEM_TIME" is defined
typedef struct SDK_SYSTEM_TIME{
    int  year;  
    int  month;  
    int  day;  
}SDK_SYSTEM_TIME;

// this is how "SDK_DeviceType" is defined
enum SDK_DeviceType
{
    SDK_DEVICE_TYPE_DVR,
    SDK_DEVICE_TYPE_MVR,
    SDK_DEVICE_TYPE_NR
};

// this is how "SocketStyle" is defined
enum SocketStyle
{
    TCPSOCKET=0,
    UDPSOCKET,
    SOCKETNR
};
```

The following is their **corresponding Java mappings**:

```
public class Test implements StdCallLibrary {
public interface simpleDLL extends StdCallLibrary {

 long H264_Login(String sIP, short wPort, String sUserName, String sPassword,
 Structure DeviceDate, int error, int TCPSOCKET);
}
static
{
   System.loadLibrary("NetSdk");
}

// the struct implementation
    public static class DeviceDate extends Structure{

        public SDK_SYSTEM_TIME tmBuildTime;
        public String sSerialNumber;      
        public IntByReference byChanNum;              
        public IntByReference uiDeviceRunTime;  
        public IntByReference deviceTpye;    
        @Override
        protected List<Object> getFieldOrder() {
            List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add("tmBuildTime");
            list.add("sSerialNumber");
            list.add("byChanNum");
            list.add("uiDeviceRunTime");
            list.add("deviceTpye");
            return list;
        }    
    }

    public static class SDK_SYSTEM_TIME extends Structure{
        public IntByReference year;  
        public IntByReference month;  
        public IntByReference day;
        @Override
        protected List<Object> getFieldOrder() {
            List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add("year");
            list.add("month");
            list.add("day");
            return list;
        }
    }

// and then how I called it through the main function
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException{

 simpleDLL INSTANCE = (simpleDLL) Native.loadLibrary( ("NetSdk"), simpleDLL.class);
 DeviceDate dev = new DeviceDate() // where DeviceDate is a static class inherits com.sun.jna.Structure
 int err = (int) INSTANCE.H264_GetLastError();

 long result = INSTANCE.H264_Login("255.255.255.255", (short) 33333, "admin", "admin", dev, err, 0);

}
}
```

upon running the app, the Java crashes:

[image]

and this is the full **problem signature**:

> **Problem signature:**
>   Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
>   Application Name:   javaw.exe
>   Application Version:    7.0.600.19
>   Application Timestamp:  536a95c6
>   Fault Module Name:  jna3976113557901128571.dll
>   Fault Module Version:   4.0.0.215
>   Fault Module Timestamp: 52d3949a
>   Exception Code: c0000005
>   Exception Offset:   0000e3a2   OS
>   Version:  6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
>   Locale ID:  1033
>   Additional Information 1:   7bc2
>   Additional Information 2:   7bc24d73a5063367529b81d28aecc01c
>   Additional Information 3:   5bea
>   Additional Information 4: 5beaa1c0441c3adb156a170a61c93d19
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
>
> If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our
>   privacy statement offline:   C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Comment: I can't understand people who just come to question, downvote, go away, at least be kind and leave a comment unless my question doesn't obey the site FAQ and I'm sure it does.

Comment: Please include the native declaration on which the Java interface definition is based.

Comment: @technomage well, I added all the required code, kindly refer to my updates.

Answer (score 0):

Your mappings have a number of errors.  Your structures should look like the following (IntByReference represents places where you would pass the *address* of an `int`, and you can't substitute `String` for a primitive native `char` array).  Please refer to [the JNA mapping documentation](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/Mappings.md) to ensure you understand how native types map to Java types:

```
public static class LP_DEVICE_INFO extends Structure{
    public SDK_SYSTEM_TIME tmBuildTime;
    public byte[] sSerialNumber = new byte[64];      
    public int byChanNum;              
    public int uiDeviceRunTime;  
    public int deviceType; // Assuming the size of the enum is int
    @Override
    protected List<Object> getFieldOrder() {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("tmBuildTime");
        list.add("sSerialNumber");
        list.add("byChanNum");
        list.add("uiDeviceRunTime");
        list.add("deviceTpye");
        return list;
    }    
}

public static class SDK_SYSTEM_TIME extends Structure{
    public int year;  
    public int month;  
    public int day;
    @Override
    protected List<Object> getFieldOrder() {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("year");
        list.add("month");
        list.add("day");
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: well, I corrected my mappings for regular data types, but I can't figure out what's the corresponding mapping to `*LP_DEVICEINFO` in Java, I tried a lot of ways (most of them are your answers to another questions) like defining a predefined size array http://stackoverflow.com/a/15431595/1638739 and declaring a StructureByReference and pass it http://stackoverflow.com/a/12144952/1638739 , and my own way to declare a null `DeviceDate[]`, all the ways cause the app to crash and despite my way doesn't but it doesn't return a struct with a predefined values as supposed.

Comment: What you need is the correct `Structure` definition (see `LP_DEVICE_INFO` above).  Definitely not `Structure[]` or some other arbitrary permutation that just happens to dereference *some* of the data correctly.